# Switch between ports based on the environment

Tags: node.js

How to switch port based on the environment in node js, I have two PORTS for dev and prod, based on the environment I need to choose the port, How can I achieve it

Answer (score 0):

```
let port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? prodPort : devPort;
```